# Silverstripe unclecheese/dashboard module does not find template

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using unclecheese/dashboard module i use it like it is described in the README. I use [silverstripe 3.5.3](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/changelogs/3.5.3/)

I get this error message:

> [User Warning] None of the following templates could be found (no
>   theme in use): DashboardMostActiveUsersPanel.ss

this is the panel content:

```
class DashboardMostActiveUsersPanel extends DashboardPanel{
 private static $db = array (
    'Count' => 'Int',
 );

 public function getLabel() {
    return 'Most Active Users';
 }


 public function getDescription() {
    return 'Shows the most active Users.';
 }


 public function getConfiguration() {
    $fields = parent::getConfiguration();
    $fields->push(TextField::create("Count", "Number of users to show"));
    return $fields;
 }



 public function getMostActiveMembers() {
    $members = Member::get()->sort("Activity DESC")->limit($this->Count);
    return  $members;
 }

 public function PanelHolder() {
    return parent::PanelHolder();
 }
}
```

this is the template:

```
<div class="dashboard-recent-orders">
<ul>
    <% loop $MostActiveMembers %>
        <li>$Name, $Activity</li>
    <% end_loop %>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is where the error comes from: `theme_enabled` is empty

```
Config::inst()->get('SSViewer', 'theme_enabled‘)
```

I set the theme in the CMS Backend and i set it in `config.yml` like

```
SSViewer:
  theme: 'my-theme'
```

I also tried to put the templates in different folders in /themes directory. But still no luck. What am i missing any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Themes only affect the frontend. The backend does not use them. You'll need to put the template in your `mysite/` directory, or whatever your `$project` is.

Comment: Any possibilty to add "default" or CMS templates to the _/themes/_ folder instead of _/mysite/templates/_?